# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, javascript, development

In my `NewForm` list I was trying to Redirect page after save button was clicked, and in my `NewForm` I have added a script editor with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]");
// change redirection behavior
    button.removeAttr("onclick");
    button.click(function() {
        var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
        var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");
        var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
        var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
        var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "http://www.google.com");

        if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
        WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
    });

});
```

but when I click save button it shows me the following error

`jquery-1.8.0.js:3061Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`

Note: I have added jquery 1.8.0 library to my script

Thanks

Comment: Is your aspnetForm selector correct? Try `$("form[name='aspnetForm']")` instead. Check that it's actually returning something. The problem is `aspForm.get(0)` is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really I tried this before to redirect after saving to another URL for  SharePoint 2013. but unfortunately it's not working , it looks like working with SharePoint 2010 .

But to overcome this error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined`

- Remove `var aspForm = $("form[name=aspnetForm]");` and `var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;`
- And set  `var oldPostbackUrl = window.location.href`

**Note** : This code will replace `Source query string` with your redirect URL and to make sure that add `alert (newPostbackUrl);` after `var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "http://www.google.com");` that will replace successfully but redirect in SharePoint 2013 will not working !

**A workaround :**

To can do that at SharePoint 2013 as a workaround

- Open your all items page and set this code
- Add Script Editor.
- Add the following code.

> ```
> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
> <script>
>
> $( document ).ready(function() {
>
> document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").removeAttribute("onclick");
>
>
> document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href="http://epm/workflow/Lists/Shoe%20Models/NewForm.aspx?Source=add your custom page url"; 
> });
>
> </script>
> ```

**Note :** At `document.getElementById("idHomePageNewItem").href=` put your link to `NewForm` page before `Source Query String` and after it add your Custom Page URL that you want to go back.

Also you can create an event receive on `Itemadded` to can redirect to your desired Url , to can create an Event Receiver Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff398052.aspx)

Comment: I have sharepoint 2013 and it is not working

Comment: after I have alerted `newPostbackUrl` I have the following result: `home.aspxhttp://Site/Lists.empribbon/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=&IsDlg=1`

Comment: this is will not work with SharePoint 2013 as I mentioned in my answer , but if you read my answer again you will know that this code tries to replace the source query string  that replaced successfully with my modification  and to make sure that at alert (newPostbackUrl); after var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue,  "http://www.google.com"); but finally it will not redirect

Comment: so do you have any idea how to redirect to my desired page?

Comment: I tried for a 2 hour to use all instruction related to this  with no luck so I tried to use Event Receiver on Itemadded  as mentioned in my updated answer this the only solution that works for me , but I didn't know if there's a simple solution rather than that or not,

Comment: I have no idea how can I change URL to redirect via event receiver

Answer (score 0):

var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]"); Use ***id*** instead of ***name***

```
var button = $("input[id$=SaveItem]").eq(1); //target the save button in the bottom
    // change redirection behavior
        button.removeAttr("onclick");
        button.click(function() {
            var elementName = $(this).attr("name");
            var aspForm = $("form[id=aspnetForm]"); //target id not name
            var oldPostbackUrl = aspForm.get(0).action;
            var currentSourceValue = GetUrlKeyValue("Source", true, oldPostbackUrl);
            var newPostbackUrl = oldPostbackUrl.replace(currentSourceValue, "<your url should be internal>");

            if (!PreSaveItem()) return false;
            WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(elementName, "", true, "", newPostbackUrl, false, true));
        });
```

If you put external url, it fails to redirect. But works with url within the site.

Hope this help

Comment: when I click save button, it happens nothing

Comment: please check my updated answer

Comment: Again it is not working, to test that javascript is working I set an alert for `newPostbackUrl ` after `var newPostbackUrl ` but even alert is not being shown, why?

Comment: Did you click on the button? debug using Chrome devloper tool

Comment: No I cannot make it work, it is not reading

Comment: Now I am able to see my alert but now it is not saving my item

Comment: Above approach will not work if the new\edit item form is open in dialogbox.